# Exposure compensation method in camera2 android

Tags: android

i am new in android. In camera, i have used `params.getMinExposureCompensation`  to get minimum brightness. How to do that in Camera2 ? 
Any example will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available exposure compensation range is reported by [CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE) and [CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP).

SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE is for manual exposure control, not for exposure compensation while using auto-exposure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range<Long> range = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);
```

this way to get the exposure time in camera2.
be careful,AE MODE shouldn't be OFF!

camera2 example:https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! 
Could you please provide any resources where i can find more about camera2 ? , f.e. about zoom effect, sharpness and so.

Comment: android SDK document.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
Range<Integer> range1 = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);

int minExposure = range1.getLower();
int maxExposure = range1.getUpper();
```