# How i can correctly set up CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION camera2API?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, ip-camera

I need to set up `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION` for my app camera2API.

i tryed to set it `captureStillPicture()` method then in `lockFocus()` method then in `stateCallback` but is doesn't work...

In documentation i found only explanation what it is, but any lines how this mode have to be set up...

There are 2 question:

1. Where exacly i have to set up this mode
2. How i can check that it is working

Or maybe you can suggest me how to reduse expose time...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [Camera2BasicFragment](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.html#l783) from [Google Camera2Basic sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) by add line

`mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION);`

just after line

`mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);`

in `onConfigured()` method of example

```
@Override
public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
    // The camera is already closed
    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        return;
    }

    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
    mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
    try {
        // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION);
        // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
        setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

        // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
        mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have alredy tryed it but after i have taken the picture i checked `exposure time` and it is doesn't chenged it is all the time `1/33` as for me... Could you suppose what is the reason?

Comment: And eventually i have tryed download google samle and chenge settings according your advice but anyway `exposure time = 1/33`(

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27689171/6950238) answer.